# NavigationStack title loads inline instead of large when sheet is presented

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

One of my views loads in a bottom sheet.
It has its own NavigationStack with a title.
Problem is that whenever the view is loaded, the title (set on ".automatic") always loads ".inline" instead.

The same happens even if I force the .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode to ".large".
The title only goes to ".large" if I scroll the view.

Tried to look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977096/navigation-title-is-inlined-instead-of-large) but it's about adding the .navigationViewStyle which will soon be deprecated (and applies to NavgationView, not NavigationStack).
Is there a way to make the title load .large?

My code for the view inside the bottom sheet:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    Form {
        // some code
    }

    .navigationTitle("Title")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. Here's a fix that works on iOS 17. Use NavigationView instead of NavigationStack.

```
/* NavigationStack { DON'T USE THIS */
NavigationView {

    Form {
        // some code
    }

    .navigationTitle("Title")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
}
```

Just note, XCode says "NavigationView will be deprecated in a future version of iOS".

Comment: NavigationView was deprecated as of iOS 17.2. No sense in recommending it as an answer. The replacement is to use either NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView depending on your needs. The documentation for NavigationView even has a link to a page telling you how to migrate away from NavigationView.

Comment: Here's the page: [Migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types)

Answer (score 3):

I'm encountering the same annoying bug. Here's my workaround for now:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BottomSheet: View {

    @State var hasAppeared: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                if hasAppeared {
                    form
                } else {
                    Color.clear
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: appeared)
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
    }
    
    var form: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Form")
        }
    }
    
    func appeared() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
            withAnimation(.snappy) {
                self.hasAppeared = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm initially displaying `Color.clear` instead of the form—this is crucial as `EmptyView()` doesn't cut it.

Then, a split second after it appears I set a flag `hasAppeared` that swaps in the form.

This fixes the issues and the transition from `Color.clear` to the form isn't noticeable.

Comment: I encourage you to use the solution by Mojtaba Hosseini. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Excellent pure SwiftUI workaround for an annoying issue

Comment: After experimentation, it seems adding `.task { hasAppeared = true }` also works

Answer (score 2):

You can work around that by using:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Put it in the `init()` or `onAppear` as it changes all navigation titles in the entire app and also you may want to disable it in `onDisappear`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain to me if this is a bug or desired behavior by Apple?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is intended or not, but when you show a sheet, there is a little space above it, and maybe Apple chose to set the `inline` mode to default to save the above space and keep the `large` state so the user can find out about reaching the top of the sheet. I didn't see a bug report about this by the way.

Comment: I added this to my SwiftUI init and it worked. It does seem to be an iOS 17 particular bug though, my screens with a large nav title are fine in iOS 16. Thank you!

Comment: Might be just in preview. But after setting it to false. I'm never able to reactive it to true again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to share your code, but for now you can force the title after view appear

```
.onAppear {
    UITableView.appearance().largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
}
```